# Telerik MVC DateTimePicker Set value in Javascript

Tags: datetimepicker, telerik-mvc

I'm setting the value of the datetime picker at client side using

```
$('#ToDate').data('tDateTimePicker').value(javascriptdateobject);
```

(I do this on client event 'OnLoad' as I couldn't find any other suitable method)

I see the value being set on the datetimepicker textbox.
However when I open the datetimepicker the date is not set in the calendar.

What additional step(s) I need to do in order to propagate the new value to the calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice. Go check the [client-api online demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/clientsideapi) for a working demonstration.

Comment: Hi Atanas, yes I also think this should be OK. However it's not. Could it be related to the fact that I'm doing this in DateTimePickers 'onLoad' event?

Comment: Should not be related. I suggest you open a forum thread in the Telerik forums and provide some code.